# Webpage is not zoomed all the way out when loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I load Kickstarter.com on my iPhone, it loads like this

[image: KickStarter]

But when I load the site I created, it loads like this

[image: Shanghai Valley]

As you can see, for KickStarter, it zoomed all the way out upon load.
For my site, it doesn't zoom all the way out. It is zoomed in to the top left hand corner of my site.

Does anyone know why this is happening? How do I make my site to have same behavior as seen on KickStarter?

thanks

Comment: This is already set in my header
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the proper scaling tags in your HTML file?

You need to have this at the top of your HTML

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this isn't a responsive design, you need to add viewport meta tags to your page

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
```

change `1024` to whatever your page width is optimized for

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in your header of the site. The "device-width" will fit the screen to the devices width.